# A common way of combining two files in Solaris and Linux

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, portability

I am trying to write a script that would combine two files into one and should work in both Solaris 5.10 and a Linux box.

**File1:**

```
dit710
dit710
dit720
dit720
```

**File2:**

```
FacA D0000000000000001
FacA D0000000000000002
FacA D0000000000000030
FacB D00000000000000980
```

**Desired Output:**

```
dit710,FacA,D0000000000000001
dit710,FacA,D0000000000000002
dit720,FacA,D0000000000000030
dit720,FacB,D00000000000000980
```

What I tried?

```
paste File1 File2 |nawk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=","
```

**(Above command works in Solaris but does not work in Linux)**

```
paste File1 File2 |awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=","
```

**(Above command works in Linux but does not work in Solaris)**

I am using Korn Shell.  Can someone suggest another way which works in both Solaris and Linux?

Note that File2 may contain more than 3 columns but always have equal number of columns.

Comment: Try `paste File1 File2 | tr '[[:blank:]]' ,`

Comment: @don_crissti Command you provided works only in Linux, its not working in Solaris.

Comment: replace `[[:blank:]]` with a literal tab followed by a space...

Comment: @don_crissti No luck, not working in solaris or linux

Comment: Solaris has an 'XPG4' option that makes many things including `awk` more like other/standard Unixen, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198905/when-to-use-xpg-version-of-a-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue myself, but I wouldn't call it a straight forward approach. Since awk works in Linux, but not nawk, I created a soft link in Linux host to redirect nawk to awk.  Now I can use nawk in both Solaris and Linux without any issues.

```
ln -s /bin/awk /bin/nawk
```

Comment: Not sure what distro you are running but Debian based distributions at least, automatically create this link.