# Solaris grep and regular expressions?

Tags: grep, solaris

We are trying to find a way to craft a GNUmakefile that works on nearly all Unix compatibles. We were using `egrep` but it failed on MinGW. We switched to `grep -E` because it is [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), but testing shows it is failing on Solaris 11.

A typical usage in the makefile is:

```
GREP ?= grep
...

IS_X86 := $(shell uname -m | $(GREP) -v "x86_64" | $(GREP) -i -c -E "i.86|x86|i86")
IS_X64 := $(shell uname -m | $(GREP) -i -c -E "(_64|d64)")
```

The result is:

```
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file . . .
...
```

I don't see where `-E` and `-F` are optional in Posix (perhaps I missed it). I found [Difference between Solaris and POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6599213/608639) on Stack Overflow, but it states, *"Solaris has a full set of POSIX interfaces ..."*.

Why is Solaris' `grep` failing to consume `-E`? Is there a way to engage regular expression support on Solaris besides switching to `egrep`?

---

I just setup a fresh test account on the Solaris 11.3 machine to ensure I did not taint the environment.

The account was added with:

```
# useradd -d /export/home/test -m -s /bin/ksh -c "Testing Accoung" test

80 blocks
```

Inspecting `PATH` after logging in:

```
test@solaris:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: you probably want to use the ones in /usr/xpg4/bin -- see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198905/when-to-use-xpg-version-of-a-command

Comment: Since you can assume a shell, you should be able to use a case statement rather than using grep. What exactly are you looking for? I can code up something once I am not on a phone.

Answer (score 8):

From [the Oracle Solaris docs (XPG)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0634/6j9vo5ann/index.html)

> #### Utilities
>
> If the behavior required by POSIX.2, POSIX.2a, XPG4, SUS, or SUSv2
>   conflicts with historical Solaris utility behavior, the original
>   Solaris version of the utility is unchanged; a new version that is
>   standard-conforming has been provided in `/usr/xpg4/bin`. For
>   applications wishing to take advantage of POSIX.2, POSIX.2a, XPG4,
>   SUS, or SUSv2 features, the `PATH` (`sh` or `ksh`) or `path` (`csh` )
>   environment variables should be set with `/usr/xpg4/bin` preceding any
>   other directories in which utilities specified by those specifications
>   are found, such as `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/ucb`, and `/usr/ccs/bin`.

If you must use extended regular expressions, set `/usr/xpg4/bin` early in your `PATH` and use `grep -E`.

Comment: Thanks. That's very unusual behavior from Solaris. They usually conform to some standard, even if its painful. I'm surprised to see a utility with arbitrary behavior at the head of the list. By the way, `/usr/ucb` is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: That's how Solaris has been [for at least two decades](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.5.1&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: Thanks @muru. I just tested on FreeBSD. FreeBSD `grep` consumes `-E`. (Did you intend to link to FreeBSD docs?)

Comment: @jww I linked to SunOS 5 docs, which are available on FreeBSD's manpage repository

Comment: Thanks again @muru. So it sounds like FreeBSD 10 and 11 are not sufficient for testing; and I need to add a new machine to my test environment. Would you happen to know which version of FreeBSD has the same behavior as Solaris? Or, do you know if FreeBSD has the `/usr/xpg4/bin` path?

Comment: Maybe try [OpenIndiana](https://www.openindiana.org/) - I doubt any version of FreeBSD did something like this (there's no need for them to).